# Metamask - disappearing tokens

Tags: tokens, metamask, pancakeswap

I've got a problem,
I bought some tokens on Pancakeswap
430 000 INX and 0,019 GRM,
I added it to metamask.
Hour by hour, my tokens was disappearing,
For now, in my wallet - i've got 9000 INX and 0,003 GRM.
BSCscan show that i have still 0,019 GRM, but only 13000 INX
What is a problem?
Is there any option to get back the losing tokens?
Best regards.

Comment: Is there any outgoing transaction? What's the address? It could be possible that the private key was compromised and someone is removing anything of value, or you bought scam token with the same name. Without more details we can only speculate.

Comment: Hello ! 
No there is no more outgoing transaction, 
You mean adress for my metamask wallet ?

Comment: There is also no option that some has my private key,

Comment: You haven't provided any details we can examine. Can you provide a link to the tokens on bscscan? Bscscan provides several tabs with token transactions, and analytics. Again without any details it is just pure speculation.

Answer (score 1):

It happened the same with me, lost the 60% of my tokens yesterday on Pancakeswap. In my case the tokens were rebase/elastic supply tokens (from a scammy source I assume). I learned the lesson and my advice is always check if the token you would like to buy is a rebase token or not.

You can read about elastic supply tokens [here on Binance](https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/elastic-supply-tokens-explained).

***Here is the most important part***

> Elastic supply tokens are highly risky and very dangerous investments.
> You should only invest in them if you completely understand what
> you’re doing. Remember, looking at price charts isn’t going to be all
> that helpful, since the amount of tokens you hold will change after
> rebases occur.
>
> Sure, this can amplify your gains to the upside, but it can also
> amplify your losses. If rebases occur while the token price is going
> down, you not only lose money from the token price going down, you’ll
> also own less and less tokens after each rebase!
>
> Since they’re quite tricky to understand, investing in rebasing tokens
> will likely result in a loss for most traders. Only invest in elastic
> supply tokens if you can fully grasp the mechanisms behind them.
> Otherwise, you’re not in control of your investment and won’t be able
> to make informed decisions.